# CloudKit Sync using private database. Works in development, but not in production

Tags: core-data, private, cloudkit

I have just added CloudKit to my app to sync my CoreData database between devices. It works great when pointing to Development. It creates all the records from my CoreData database in the private container on CloudKit. When I change it to point to Production, it doesn't work. I get the error:

"Cannot create new type [one of my types] in production schema"

I'm not sure if this is an issue, but it says this under my container on the Dashboard: "This container has not been deployed to Production." Since I'm only using Private database, I assume I don't have to deploy anything to Production? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this. It turns out I was misunderstanding something. I learned that even when using only a Private database, we still need to deploy schema changes to Production via the CloudKit dashboard.